# How do I reorder the what appears on the single product page in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I want to reorder the things that display on the WooCommerce. For example I want the product excerpt to be above the add to cart button. How is that changed?

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress WooCommerce **single product page displays the product excerpt or short description above the add to cart button** by default.

Assume the commented block below provides the default position or priority of the elements on a page.

- The product title being in position 5.
- product price in position 10 and so on.
- You want to move the product excerpt above add to cart button which is    position 20
- The add to cart button position 30.

  ```
   <?php

     /**
      * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
      *
      * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
      * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
      * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
      * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
      * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
      * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
      * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
      */
       do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary');
    ?>
  ```

In this product excerpt to be above the add to cart button.